# How to import certificate on new mac if forgot certificate password

Tags: ios

I have implemented Push-Notification in my application
I have an application which is live on an apple store, Application also have push-notification functionality.
Unfortunately my mac was crashed and not working, So i setup the project on my new mac. When i am importing certificates using organizer i am getting an error.
"Unable to code sign using identities in this team. No valid certificates with private keys found"
Please tell me how should i approach to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: There are two ways: (1) Try to recall the password, or (2) get a new cert.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new certificate and provisioning profile using the same app id, it will not affect your app store app.

To prevent this happening in the future export your certificates using XCode.